How do you test animations in flutter?
I didn't find any information, but looking at the flutter code I think it's with AnimationSheetBuilder in a golden tests.
Is that the correct way? or is there any other way to test animations?
Thank you
Like here
  testWidgets('Material3 - Indeterminate CircularProgressIndicator uses expected animation', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final AnimationSheetBuilder animationSheet = AnimationSheetBuilder(frameSize: const Size(40, 40));
    addTearDown(animationSheet.dispose);

    await tester.pumpFrames(animationSheet.record(
      Theme(
        data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
        child: const Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ), const Duration(seconds: 2));

    await expectLater(
      animationSheet.collate(20),
      matchesGoldenFile('m3_material.circular_progress_indicator.indeterminate.png'),
    );
  }, skip: isBrowser); // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56001

Result for the golden test is the image.
Golden test image generated
Thanks

Barring some extremely specific circumstances involving some truly esoteric edge cases, I can't see this test being useful or meaningful in any way. All you should need to worry about for automated testing is whether the animation loaded (if applicable) and is playing. Once those are confirmed to be working, a one-time visual verification that the animation looks to be playing the correct frames should be sufficient.

A golden test is the only practical way to verify all aspects of an animation are working. An animation is visual, and therefore must be seen to be verified.
You could attempt to verify what shapes are painted on the screen using paints, but I imagine doing so with even a basic animation would be difficult or impossible.
Depending on how your animation is set up and what objects you have access to in your tests, you could verify objects and their parameters instead of the actual animation. For example, if you use a built-in widget from Flutter like AnimatedContainer, you could use the WidgetTester to find this widget and check that it has the parameters you expect. If you create a custom animation and your test can access the Animation object your UI uses, you could test this animation object directly to make sure it provides the right values.
I mention that for completeness but wouldn't recommend it. It depends on your exact implementation what's possible and depends on how sure you want to be that the animation works. If you spend effort on doing that, you might as well make a golden test which is much easier and actually verifies the animation itself.
An important thing to know about golden tests is that they can cause issues if you're working on a project with other developers. The golden images can render differently based on the platform, so to avoid test flakiness you need to have a dedicated server to build the golden images.
If you want to get a feel for what animations look like with an AnimationSheetBuilder, here's the golden image of that same Flutter test you mentioned. A single pixel rendered incorrectly and this golden test will catch it.

https://flutter-gold.skia.org/search?corpus=flutter&include_ignored=false&left_filter=name%3Dmaterial.m3_material.circular_progress_indicator.indeterminate&max_rgba=0&min_rgba=0&negative=true&not_at_head=false&positive=true&reference_image_required=false&right_filter=&sort=descending&untriaged=true

Very rich answer.
